# Aptana Code Assist with custom Class Loader

Tags: intellisense, aptana, code-assist

Is it possible to setup Aptanta to provide code assist for classes loaded with a framework's autoloading class?

For example:

```
$myInstance = Project_Loader::load('MyClass');
```

Here, my class would be loaded from a hierarchy as soon as it was found, so if I had these libraries setup:

```
/library/Library1
/library/Library2
/library/Library3
```

If MyClass was in Library2, it wound find `Library2_MyClass`.  Aptana works great if I initiate the object using:

```
$myInstance = new Library2_MyClass();
```

But is there any way to let Aptana know to load it and use Code Assist/Intellisense based on `Project_Loader::load('MyClass')`?

Comment: Would love an answer to this when using CakePHP as well!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at the moment, as it's very dynamic, and specific to a framework.

What you can do is to add a comment that will hint for the type.

For example:

```
/* @var $myInstance MyClass*/
$myInstance-> // and you'll get the MyClass code-assist.
```

Comment: I've tried with your example and all sorts of variations /* (at)var, /** (at)var, /*(at)var, different spacing, etc, but Aptana will not pick it up.  I'm on Aptana 3.0.9.201202141038  (Just updated it today).  (PS: I had to replace at symbol with (at) otherwise StackOverflow thinks I'm trying to name someone and won't let me comment)

Comment: (1) Verify that your project is a PHP project (Project -> Properties -> Project Natures have Aptana PHP nature checked there ("PHP"). (2) Make sure that the `MyClass` is accessible in that project. That is, it's inside the project itself, or is linked as an external library (see https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/PHP+Development#PHPDevelopment-AttachingPHPResources )